# Upgrading ASP.NET Core 1.1 to ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my csproj file under `ItemGroup` element, I have individual packages referenced -- all pointing to 1.1.

In this article that outlines the steps to upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.0, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/, under section "Update Package References", it states that a single meta package reference takes care of all references to ASP.NET Core 2.0 and Entity Framework Core 2.0 -- unless I'm misinterpreting it.

Does this mean, I should remove all the references to ASP.NET Core packages? I also have a bunch of package references to `AspNetCore.Authentication` such as `Cookies`, `Facebook`, `Google`, etc.

If I am to remove all individual references, how do I know what to remove and what to keep?

Comment: Cannot you create a simple ASP.NET Core 2.0 project and then check it out? That should clearly show you what works and what not.

Comment: When I had individual references, I got NuGet error. After I removed all individual ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core references and used a single `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />` reference, the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft.AspNetCore.All literally brings in all of Asp.Net Core

All the packages sync together (2.0.0) & already as a part of installing .NET core package.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage

> The Microsoft.AspNetCore.All metapackage for ASP.NET Core includes:
>
> All supported packages **by the ASP.NET Core team**.
>
> All supported packages by the Entity Framework Core.
>
> Internal and 3rd-party dependencies used by ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core.

ASP.NET Core 2.0 new features demo

https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/dotnet/NET-Core-20-Released#time=0h48m26s

If you want to check **manually**, you can do it with VS 2017 15.3

[image]

Comment: Isn't this a bit heavy? Not sure if I had all these references in my version 1.1 app. I guess we still have the option to reference them individually if I wanted to lighten this up.

Comment: It already as a part of installing .NET core 2.0 package. So It's very light when publishing. Take a look at Channel 9 video.

Comment: Not too concerned about publishing. I meant running the app. Aren't all these loaded onto memory on Azure App Service? Would like my app to be as light and fast as possible.

Comment: Only used packages are loaded